# TypeScript config can't resolve custom paths with ESM enabled

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've been trying to crack this thing down for quite a while now, I want my tsconfig.json paths to be resolved when ESM is enabled for my project, the whole reason I'm doing is
because I want to achieve top-level await in the long run.

My project structure is something along the lines of,

```
- build
- node_modules
- src
  -| something
     - | foo.ts
  -| server.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
yarn.lock
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "wotd-backend",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.6.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "fastify": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "execute": "node ./build/server.js",
    "dev": "ts-node ./src/server.ts"
  }
}
```

The only notable change here is `"type": "module"`

tsconfig.json, I will be removing the comments from this one for readability

```
{
  "extends": "ts-node/node16/tsconfig.json",
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true,
    "require": [ "tsconfig-paths/register" ],
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",

    "compilerOptions": {}
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "ES2022", "DOM"
    ],
    "module": "ES2022",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": { 
      "@something/*": [ "something/*" ]
    },
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Notable changes here are the ts-node options which I'm using inside the tsconfig.json for simplicity sake for the example it's also recommended by ts-node itself https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#via-tsconfigjson-recommended

Now, one of the issues I'm facing is that tsconfig-paths doesn't actually resolve my paths and I get the following error message when I run the `yarn dev` command this is in accordance with this section https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#paths-and-baseurl

`CustomError: Cannot find package '@something/foo'`

this looks be thrown from the ESM resolver module of ts-node

`throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(packageName, fileURLToPath(base));`

Those are the issues I'm currently facing at this stage, I've been trying to read and test about the issue for a couple of weeks now, to no avail.

One hypothesis I have, is that I might need to "hack" the way ts-node esm resolves the modules that way I might achieve the behaviour I want, but I really want to avoid doing this.

Lastly, I'm unsure if I need to have `includes: [], excludes: []` options on my tsconfig.json.

For completeness sake, here is the code in two of my files

src/something/foo.ts

```
export default function foo() {
  console.log( "foo" );
}
```

src/server.ts

```
import foo from "@something/foo";

foo();

console.log( "bar" );
```

Comment: See if any of [these suggestions](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths/issues/157) work for you.

Comment: Sadly, none of the suggestions seem to solve my issue at hand, as mentioned at the start the end goal is top-level await.

Comment: @WarturtleChips99 have you figured it out?